# How could I remove a header in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes

I'm editing a theme beamer, but I have a trouble I would like to remove the header without remove neither footer or the lateral navigation bar. I've tried with the follow option:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{split theme}
{

 %nothing  

}
```

but when I try to compile I receive the follow error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \beamer@@tmpop@headline@split theme already defined.
```

I use theme `PaloAlto`. I hope that somebody can help me.

EDIT by Marco Daniel:

Here the solution presented as a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{bar}
Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it) or CTRL+K. The syntax highlighter already defaults to (La)TeX. It is also not necessary to use a LaTeX tag on this site, especially not `tex-core` which is about the lower level of TeX.

Comment: Use: `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}`

Comment: According to the [`beamer` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (p 172, section **16.3.3 Setting Beamer's Templates**) regarding `\defbeamertemplate`: "This command installs a predefined option for the template `<element name>`. Once this command has been
used, users can access the predefined template using the `\setbeamertemplate` command." Does using `\setbeamertemplate` work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work, the header is there still.

Comment: Please then add a full but [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: I edited you post

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: "Here the solution presented ..."???

Comment: I've discovered what was wrong, i was using this:

    \useoutertheme{shadow}

So the changes didn't work.


Thank you to everyone.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I want to present a minimal working example. The OP wasn't able to provide one. With the example he had a basis. ;-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The solution is to use `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}`.  This clears the "template" for the headline, ensuring that when the headline is typeset then nothing is done.  It is important to ensure that this is *not* overridden by other styles so should be placed in the preamble after any themes have been loaded.

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{bar}
Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: beamer with no header]

With the `\setbeamertemplate` command commented out then it produces:

[image]

---

(This was answered in the comments; I'm posting this to remove it from the "unanswered" queue.  As the *real* problem was due to a theme overriding the template, I considered having it closed as "too localised", but I also thought that this might be a common question and having the question closed with the answer in the comments is not the most helpful way to present this question and answer.  I've marked it CW partly as it's not my answer and partly so that others can easily improve it and know that they are encouraged to do so.)

Comment: Yes I't was the solution. Thank you to everyone.