# Beamer Theme: Getting rid of the two boxes in the header

Tags: beamer, themes

In the CambridgeUS theme in Beamer (and I guess also in other themes), there are two boxes in the header appearing on each slide: [image]

Personally, I'd like to remove them, as they do not contain any necessary information, how can this be done?

Comment: Next time please add an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) so that there is less risk of misunderstandings.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66925 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179304/

Comment: You should provide an mwe as mentioned earlier. Otherwise, it is too much guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is proposal.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33146
% In my case, first hit when googeling for "CambridgeUS beamer header remove" :).
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} % < --- ---

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    Content.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Important:** When using sections etc., the headline has a purpose, see:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    Content.
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    Content.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the proposal and the comment regarding the usefulness of the header when using comments! Concerning your proposal: I added the line, but unfortunately, just as is in your case, there is now instead of the header white space. Ideally, I'd like to remove the white space as well, could you help me on that as well?

Comment: This is why you need to provide an mwe, see my comment below your question. Otherwise there is too much guessing involved.

Comment: Sorry, my question has already resolved itself. I had not put `setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` before `\begin{document}`, that was my mistake.